# Get online users XMPP4r + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmpp, ejabberd, xmpp4r

I'm trying get online friends by user in XMPP server (Ejabberd). I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2.
The idea is to add in array all online users to use this on view page.

I found asynchronous code (below), but it use Thread and it's difficult to work on controller method.

```
jid = Jabber::JID.new('user@localhost')

cl = Jabber::Client.new(jid)
cl.connect
cl.auth('123456')
@online_users = [] #online users queue
roster = Jabber::Roster::Helper.new(cl)

mainthread = Thread.current

roster.add_presence_callback { |item,oldpres,pres|
  if item.online?
    @online_users.push item
  else
    @online_users.delete_if {|x| x.jid == item.jid }
  end  
  puts @online_users.inspect
  puts "#{item.jid} - online: #{item.online?}" 
}

cl.send(Jabber::Presence.new.set_show(:dnd))

t = Thread.new { sleep XMPP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT;   mainthread.wakeup;}
Thread.stop

cl.close
```

So I need some synchronous code, or some way to execute this kind of code in controller method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this found another solution that help me:

I installed a [mod_rest](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_rest/) in ejabberd server. This module allow that you do HTTP request  of terminal commands of **ejabberdctl**.

So it has "ejabberdctl connected_users", that return users online.

So in your model app using **gem rest-client** you can do something like it:

```
def online_users
    response = RestClient.post('http://localhost:5280/rest', "connected_users")
    response
end
```

Comment: BIG +1 what a neat implementation. Is it possible to manipulate rosters in this way also?

Comment: Yeah.All methods used with ejabberdctl you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You will be much happier in the long run if you use a library like [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) to do this in the browser, talking to an XMPP server that has [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) enabled.  Snapshots of presence are never anywhere as interesting as you expect them to be, and you're going to have really bad authentication/authorization problems on the path down which you're heading.